# Triangle that collapse cells

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options

I'm not very good in English , so is hard to explain but how put the triangle in the left that deploy or collapse a group of cells ?

> [image]

Comment: Use `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowGroupOpener -> True]` to show the opener icon  next to the first cell in a cell group.

Comment: Also have a look at [`Opener`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opener.html) and ['OpenerView'](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenerView.html)

Comment: Opener ! Thank I look in the documentation but I had no idea how to call it

Comment: I believe it's `cucarakafka`

Comment: That's my cousin XD

Comment: @Kafkarudo remember to start your comments with "@username", otherwise the intended receiver won't be notified

Comment: @belisarius That's my cousin. 

Comment: @Kafkarudo Con ese nombre, argentino o yorugua, fijo

Comment: @belisarius uruguayo! Jaja y vos sos argentino o porteño ?

Comment: @Kafkarudo http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius

Comment: closely: [265](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/265/5478), [62936](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/62936/5478)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Several ways to make the opener icon for cell groups visible:

You can set the `ShowGroupOpener` to `True` for the current notebook using

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowGroupOpener -> True]
```

If you want the icon to show in all notebooks in the current front-end session use

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, ShowGroupOpener -> True]
```

To get the opener icon showing in all later sessions, use

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ShowGroupOpener -> True]
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Option Inspector` under the `Format` menu and change the value of `ShowGroupOpener` under `Cell Options >> Display Options` to `True`

[image]

Comment: I suggest you add that you can also do this at the Style Sheet level. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I am drawing a blank on how to do this using  `StyleSheet`s. If you don't mind could you please suggest a way or post a seperate answer?

Comment: I mean that you can set `ShowGroupOpener` for a `StyleData` cell in a style sheet to add an opener to all cells of that style.  You could of course also create a new style, inheriting from an existing one if needed, that has an opener, then adding an opener is as easy as setting a style (which can be assigned a keyboard shortcut).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and kglr, do you know what is the best way to show the opener only for headings, but not for input/output cell pairs?  Is there anything simpler than specifying it in the stylesheet individually for each heading style?

Comment: @Szabolcs How about setting `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowGroupOpener -> True]` and then putting an explicit `ShowGroupOpener -> False` on the `Input` style in the stylesheet?  Or do you mean something else?