# how can i make togglable cells in a mathematica presentation?

Tags: slideshows

I'm having trouble understanding how to make togglable cells in presentations in mathematica. In the notebooks I download from the website training, when I click a title or so it toggles the open cells, as show in the image below.

[image: togglable cells]

However when i create a slideshow from scratch (using the slideshow palette), I always get an edit cursor. Trying to close open cells with shortcuts or using the little bars on the right is not nearly as nice as just clicking on a title.

[image: togglable cells]

Comment: Thanks for asking - formatting baffles.

Answer (score 6):

After some frustrating hunting around, I think I found it. You have to enable this option in the option inspector (for the selected cells or the selected notebook):

```
ShowGroupOpener
WholeCellGroupOpener
```

This will lead to the desired behaviour.

[image: toggle group opener options]