# Button for expanding a cell?

Tags: button, style

How can I create a button which sits next to the cell, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/32SuA.jpg

When you click the button it expands the cell, like this (note the cells on the right): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGyJx.jpg

I can't find any code inside the Mathematica notebook for creating the button.

Duplicate of: [Triangle that collapse cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57463/triangle-that-collapse-cells)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the option [`ShowGroupOpener`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ShowGroupOpener.html) to `True`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowGroupOpener -> True]
```

You can also use `$FrontEnd`  (resp., `$FrontEndSession`) instead of `EvaluationNotebook[]` to get the effect for the current and future front-end sessions (resp., the current session).

Alternatively, you can use the `OptionInspector` from the `Format` menu:

[image]

to set this option at theselected cell, selected notebook or global level.

Comment: Thanks! Can I delete the cell after evaluating it?

Comment: @Lightvvind, you mean the cell with command `SetOptions[...]`?

Comment: Yes, or do I need to keep it in the notebook?

Comment: @Lightvvind, you can make that line a self-destructing one (see, for example, [this q/a](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17985/125)). However, using the option inspector is probably easier/cleaner.